# How does this technique protect against malicious input?

Tags: android, provider

In the android content provider guide, it says that when selecting data from database, to not use `String mSelectionClause = "var = " + mUserInput` because if `mUserInput` is `nothing; DROP TABLE *;` then the whole table will be dropped.

So it recommends this way:

```
String mSelectionClause = "var = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = {""};
selectionArgs[0] = mUserInput;
```

I don't get it, so if the value of `mUserInput` is `nothing; DROP TABLE *;`, won't it do the same thing with `String mSelectionClause = "var = nothing; DROP TABLE *;"`?

Comment: are you talking about parameterised sql? The use of built in methods tend to prevent malicious attacks for you. As opposed to a raw string input. Aka, in your example string, it will deny the use of `;` to start a new query.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking.  Are you asking why parameterised queries protect from SQL injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question mark in the query is **not** directly replaced with the value (`mUserInput`)!

The internal mechanisms of the database and/or executing (code) libraries, know how to make the provided value safe in order to prevent [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and other malicious attacks.

*Note*: This technique is not Android specific, but is (or at least should be) able for all databases in all programming languages/environments.